# Understanding lambda in razor/blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I am very new to razor syntax & C# generally, and I am just working through a few blazor courses and got stuck getting my head around the use of a lambda in one of the examples (here for ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1#build-a-todo-list

this bit:

```
<h3>Todo (@todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h3>
```

The whole code is below... my problem is that I understand that it is evaluating whether members of the **todos** list are true/false, and then putting the **count** of these onto the page, and  also that **todo** is a local variable within the Lambda (because if I change it to **todoxxx => !todoxxx.IsDone** it still works).

What I don't understand is how it is checking each entry in the **todos** list to evaluate it?

I apologise profusely in advance for what is probably a very simple question!

```
@page "/todo"

<h3>Todo (@todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" />
            <input @bind="todo.Title" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add todo</button>

@code {
    private IList<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();
    private string newTodo;

    private void AddTodo()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add that I tried to replicate this as a console app using 
```
Console.WriteLine(myTodoObj.todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone));
```
and I got an error **Non-Invocable member 'ICollection<TodoItem<.Count' cannot be used like a method** and then prompted me to add **using System.Linq** which fixed the console app...

Comment: This is indeed a basic C# question, not at all related to your [blazor] or [razor] tags. Google for a tutorial about Linq and lambda's. The code in question is an inline version of `bool Check(ToDo todo) { return !todo.IsDone; }`

Comment: If I might just ask one other thing.... I don't have a **using System.Linq** statement in my _Imports.razor file, and it still works OK, so what provides that functionality for the lambda in asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the [IEnumerable.Count](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1329), you will see that, behind the scenes, it does exactly that:

- Runs a `foreach` loop on the collection;
- Tests your lambda code against every collection member;
- If lambda results in `true` then the counter variable is incremented;
- In the end, it returns the counter value.

In this particular context, your lambda is essentially treated like a function pointer, only this time with a strongly defined interface: it takes a single parameter of whatever type you have in your collection, and returns `bool`.

Regarding where the `System.Linq` reference comes from and how it is resolved without an explicit `@using`, it seems that Razor components are actually partial classes, with their other parts "hidden" (meaning autogenerated by the compiler). For your particular example, if you go to the `\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Razor\Pages` folder in your project, you will find there a file named "Todo.razor.g.cs", which contains the following:

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Pages
{
    #line hidden
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
...
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/todo")]
    public partial class Todo : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Which means that these 5 namespaces are always available in all components, regardless of the `_Imports.razor` contents. Not sure why these particular ones have been chosen, that's probably a question for Microsoft.

Comment: Count => Counts the elements in a collection, optionally only those elements that satisfy a predicate function.

Comment: @enet, yes, I know that. The OP's question was "how it is checking each entry in the todos list to evaluate it?". Well, that's how it does it.

Comment: @user3620419, Did you see the code you were linked too ? It's really simple. I've never seen it before. You don't have to understand " how it is checking each entry in the todos list to evaluate it?", in order to code, just as much as you don't have to understand the internals of Blazor in order to create an SPA application...

Comment: @enet, thanks. However, I can attest from personal experience (being a completely database-centric person for 15 years) that things like lambdas are not at all obvious for newcomers. I remember being befuddled with them, too, when I just started to learn .NET.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone for the replies, you've been very helpful!  Yes that code is perfect for a blazor intro, but I wanted to be sure I understood the lambda aspect, which  like Henk mentioned is more of a general C# thing....
Spent the las hour reading up on Linq, so makes more sense now, the only other thing was as per my last comment, I don't have a using System.Linq statement in my _Imports.razor file, and it still works OK, so what provides that functionality for the lambda in asp.net?